# error posting images to my bucket in google cloud storage

Tags: post, bucket, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with the acl set to Allusers and Full_control, so that users can post  and retrieve images from  the bucket.

. I have tried using this url (http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/bucket/+Image.png) to post images from my app; but i get the "error 1104, the image cannot be posted with the url provided. 
here is my alc for the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessControlList>
    <Owner>
        <ID>
            00b50024a97592382732e7e69afac5fcba343397379237323e5ebd216831a418023820874872
        </ID>
    </Owner>
    <Entries>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="AllUsers"/>
            <Permission>
                FULL_CONTROL
            </Permission>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="GroupById">
                <ID>
                    00b4903a2853501162e8e89afac5fcba14239486e5ebd216831a419323059585
                </ID>
            </Scope>
            <Permission>
                FULL_CONTROL
            </Permission>
        </Entry>
    </Entries>
</AccessControlList>
```

Comment: Can you add more info about how you're formulating your request? A code snippet illustrating the logic used to build the post request and a corresponding request/response trace would be helpful.

Comment: KC sent me the source. It is an App Inventor program and the source is   yail, which comes from kawa which comes from the language Scheme. I can put the source here, but his program does not get an auth token.      I am going to work with him to move it forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sending me the source. Your program is written with App Inventor and does not have the Auth token.

App Inventor can get the token, but you need to know what to do.
I am working on documenting that flow for others, I'll work with you to get you going and also follow up with a working example here.

Gary

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an ACL problem. Can you try without the + at the beginning of the object name? i.e. image.png rather than +image.png?